# iPhone List Based Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a list based application that uses Core Data to store most information, and the document directory just to save images since they are too large.  I really want to give the user a way to backup there data, but I do not want to use a server of my own.

I'm not sure if the user backing up there data on iCloud will include all my app's pictures store in the documents directory or not.  Any recommendations on a clean, easy solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should backup the Documents directory. Storing cache files there has led to App Store rejections since the introduction of iCloud, for this very reason.

Comment: I'm storing the actual image there, are you saying that is not allowed anymore?

Comment: No, I'm saying that storing *cache* files there is not allowed. So if your actual images are just downloaded files that you cache locally, you should store them in the Caches directory. If they are genuine Documents, from the perspective of your app, store them in Documents. I think Apple has some decent documentation of all this btw.